# Compare files in two different directories in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, file-diffs

A shell script which shows differences in multiple files in two different directories and also possibly create an output file including where all mismatches were found.

Condition

1. File dir1/file1 compare only with dir2/file1 (similarly for other files - file2  compare with file2)
2. If any changes found: status should be "Miss-match FOUND in file file1 for example" and same thing should do for all other files as well and write a all of the results into a one file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Use the diff command. Using the `-r` flag you can compare folders recursively:

```
diff -ur dir1 dir2
```

The output will be in a format which the `patch` command understands. You can save it in a file and apply those changes to `dir1` using

```
diff -ur dir1 dir2 > my.patch
cd dir1
patch -p1 < ../my.patch
```

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
diff -ur /tmp/testr/adir1 /tmp/test/adir2 >my.patch
cd /tmp/anwar/adir1
patch -p1<../my.patch


bash-3.2$ bash files-compare
patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input`

Comment: It should be patch -p2 in that case

Comment: thanks - just tried with patch -p2 with same results - not sure why.

Comment: I am more interested in seeing those files where mis-match found ( file size or if there count differences as well)

Comment: The output from `diff` can be changed and formatted. You need to go through `man diff` and play around with those options.

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with text files and want to just see the differences, I would customize the diff output, as hek2mgl suggested. But if you want more control, for example to execute some commands after finding different files or you must compare binary files, you may utilize `find` and `cmp`.
Below is the sample, which you may customize:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS_SAVE="$IFS"
IFS=$'\x0a'

for f in $(find dir1 -type f -printf "%f\n"); do {
    f1="dir1/$f"
    f2="dir2/$f"
    cmp --quiet "$f1" "$f2"
    check=$?
    if [ $check -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo -e "OK: $f"
    elif [ $check -eq 1 ] ; then
        echo -en "Mismatch FOUND in files: "
        filesize1=$(stat --printf="%s" "$f1" )
        filesize2=$(stat --printf="%s" "$f2" )
        echo "$f1" size:"$filesize1" "$f2" size:"$filesize2" check:"$check" 
        #you may put diff ... or anything else here
    else 
        echo "cannot compare files, probably $f2 is missing"
    fi
} ; done
IFS="$IFS_SAVE"
```

*Depending on your situation (if filenames do not contain spaces, there are no missing files, etc.) you may omit some parts - this was just tailored from a larger script.*

Comment: thanks for your suggestions - I tried running this where I am trying to compare two directories however I am getting some error not sure where is the problem - I know I do have files in dir2 but it's still erroring off dir2 dir

`bash-3.2$ ./file-comp-latest
cannot compare files, probably dir2/file2 is missing
cannot compare files, probably dir2/file9 is missing
cannot compare files, probably dir2/file1 is missing
cannot compare files, probably dir2/file3 is missing`

Comment: I have checked the script on test data before posting, so it is OK. Now, you must find out why it behaves like that with your data. Try to understand the flow of the program. The output means that `cmp` throws an error. Remove the `--quiet` switch. Add some `echo` statements before to see what is in `$f1` and `$f2`. Run the `cmd` statements directly from terminal with the same parameters. Go on.

Comment: ok. great it works for me now. Thanks a lot for your help. However there are slightly change in requirement which I am trying to accomplish but not sure how to go about this.

here is situation:
I will need to pass four arguments to the script as follows:
<script> <ArchiveDir> <SourceDir> <zipFilefromArchivedir> <non-zipfilefromsource>

and my goal is to be able to compare files in archivedir and sourcedir while files are in archivedir in .gz however same nonzip files are in sourcedir - not sure how I can go about this. any idea?